# Cross-server query does not work in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server

I've read up on how to do a cross-server query:

`serverName.DBName.SchemaName.TableName`

I do just this and I get an error telling me that the server is not found on sys.servers. I queried sys.servers but I just see my own server's name and nothing else.

--Am I missing something? The error message also gives me a stored procedure's name. But I am just not sure why this is not working, shouldn't it be working just fine?? I do have credentials/permissions on BOTH servers to read and write. So I don't think it's a permission thing.

Error message:

> Could not find server 'targetServerName' in sys.servers. Verify that
>   the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the
>   stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Comment: Add a linked server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a link to the other servers. You can do this with the [`sp_addlinkedserver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) stored procedure or via the Sql Server Management Studio gui.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this mandatory? Is there a reason why I need to link them? (I just looked up that SP and realized it needs to be there, but I'm trying to find out why... I don't think I have permission to link them together. Is there an alternative if I don't have that kind of DBA permission?)

Comment: Is there an alternative way of achieving this?

Comment: I think "mandatory" speaks for itself here. Your alternatives are to copy the data to the local database server.